# Perl - Recursive Function that Calls itself for unravelling hash of arrays whose elements might be keys in the same hash

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I want to write a `Perl` function that will read a hash with particular, nested formatting and transfer its contents into a hash with different formatting. The input hash is a hash of arrays in which all keys and all array elements are numbers. The numbers represent nodes in a phylogenic tree. There are no duplicate array elements (nor any duplicate keys obviously) throughout the hash but some array elements correspond to keys; every number in a hash appears exactly once or twice. Here is an example:

```
my %hash_A = ( '1' => [2,7,9], 
               '2' => [3,5],
               '3' => [4], 
               '5' => [6],
               '7' => [8] );
```

The desired output hash would be a hash of arrays in which every number in the hash is a key pointing to itself, any elements it points to and any elements that it its elements point to. Here is the desired output from %hash_A:

```
my %hash_B = ( '1' = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
               '2' = [2,3,4,5,6],
               '3' = [3,4],
               '4' = [4],
               '5' = [5,6],
               '6' = [6],
               '7' = [7,8],
               '8' = [8],
               '9' = [9] );
```

Note that `$hash_B{'2'}` contains:

- itself
- 3 and 5 that it pointed to in `%hash_A`
- 4 and 6 that 3 and 5 pointed to in `%hash_A`

While `%hash_B{'1'}` contains every element in the entire hash since they are elements of... what I would like to call "sub-hashes" but that doesn't seem structurally accurate.

I started writing a subroutine that would loop through the `%hash_A` populating `%hash_B` but its been a slow confusing process and I can't even tell if I'm on the right track. I think I need to write the function in such a way that it can call itself in the middle of a loop to follow the trail of each `array_element => key => array_element => key => array_element` to the end. Here's my subroutine (that doesn't work):

```
sub one_level_deeper {
    my ($ref) = @_;
    my %hash_B;
    foreach my $k (keys %$ref) {
         push(@{$hash_B{$k}}, $k);
         my @temp_array = @$ref{$k};
         foreach ( @temp_array ) {
             if (exists $$ref{$k} ) {
                 my %temp_hash = &one_level_deeper($$ref{$k}); #HASH CALLS ITSELF
                 push(@{$hash_B{$k}}, $temp_hash{$k});
             }
             push(@{$hash_B{$k}}), $_;
         }
    }
return(%hash_B);
}
```

**I would like feedback on how produce `%hash_B` from `%hash_A` either by fixing my subroutine or by some other method in Perl.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it may be much clearer if you explained what the numbers in your data signified

What you have is a *directed graph*. The original data represents just the children of each node, while your desired result lists all *descendants*

You must build a data structure that incorporates all of your known information and allows you to query it regarding the relationship between two nodes

I think the CPAN [`Graph`](http://search.cpan.org/~jhi/Graph-0.9704/lib/Graph.pod) module suite will probably do all that you need. Unfortunately I am using my tablet at present so I cannot write example code. But it should be straightforward, and I will check this question in the morning if I'm spared

---

#### Update

Here's the code that I intended. In a graph, all data points are called *edges* and all relationships are called *edges*. This program simply builds the graph by assigning all edges from `%hash_A` and then reads back the list of descendants for each vertex using the `all_successors` method. Ordinarily a vertex isn't considered to be one of its own successors, but you seem to want that in you case so I've explicitly added every vertex to its own list of `@descendants`. The resultant list is inserted into `%hash_B` for each vertex

I've printed out the values as `%hash_B` is being built, and also displayed the result using `Data::Dump`. It's identical to the *desired output* that you show

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Graph;

my %hash_A = (
    '1' => [2,7,9], 
    '2' => [3,5],
    '3' => [4], 
    '5' => [6],
    '7' => [8],
);

my $graph = Graph->new(directed => 1);

while ( my ($from, $to) = each %hash_A ) {
    $graph->add_edge($from, $_) for @$to;
}

my %hash_B;

for my $from ( sort { $a <=> $b } $graph->vertices ) {
    my @descendants = sort { $a <=> $b } ($from, $graph->all_successors($from));
    printf "%d -> %s\n", $from, join ', ', @descendants;
    $hash_B{$from} = \@descendants if @descendants;
}
print "\n";

use Data::Dump;
dd \%hash_B;
```

#### output

```
1 -> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
2 -> 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
3 -> 3, 4
4 -> 4
5 -> 5, 6
6 -> 6
7 -> 7, 8
8 -> 8
9 -> 9

{
  1 => [1 .. 9],
  2 => [2 .. 6],
  3 => [3, 4],
  4 => [4],
  5 => [5, 6],
  6 => [6],
  7 => [7, 8],
  8 => [8],
  9 => [9],
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Following up on Borodin's suggestion to use Graph:

```
use Graph::Directed;
my $graph = Graph::Directed->new;

# Build a graph from the input data
for my $source (keys %hash_A) {
  for my $dest (@{ $hash_A{$source} }) {
    $graph->add_edge($source => $dest);
  }
}

# For each vertex retrieve its descendants (plus itself).
my %hash_B;
for my $vertex ($graph->vertices) {
  $hash_B{$vertex} = [ 
    sort { $a <=> $b } 
    $vertex, $graph->all_successors($vertex) 
  ];
}
```

The `sort` makes the output match what's in your question, but if the order of the values in each output array don't actually matter to you, you can leave it out.